# Не запускается Django

Tags: django

Пишу

```
django startprojeckt mysite
```

и мне отвечает

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 179, in fetch_command
    app_name = commands[subcommand]
KeyError: 'startpojeckt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 182, in fetch_command
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: Ну как минимум команды startpojeckt действительно не существует.

Answer (score 1):

Неверная команда, правильная:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

[Ссылка на документацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project)